# VSTO: Security error when updating Outlook Addin to a new version with a new certificate

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

We have a plug-in that runs on Outlook 2016. Our plug-in is using VSTOInstaller.exe file to install new updates from the installation folder URL. Now, the certificate of our plug-in is about to expire, so we bought a new certificate and deployed a new version with the new certificate.

But during the installion of the new update with the new certificate, the plug-in have encountered a security error that is preventing it from updating to the new version, see error below:

Exception: Customized functionality in this application will not work because it has not been granted trust. The certificate used to sign the deployment manifest is unknown, and the customization itself (Time Tracking System) is not on the inclusion list. Contact your administrator for further assistance.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Security.SecurityException: Customized functionality in this application will not work because it has not been granted trust. The certificate used to sign the deployment manifest is unknown, and the customization itself (Time Tracking System) is not on the inclusion list. Contact your administrator for further assistance.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.OfficeAddInDeploymentManager.VerifyAddInTrust(ClickOnceAddInTrustEvidence evidence)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.VerifySecurity(ActivationContext context, Uri manifest, AddInInstallationStatus installState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer

After searching for a solution over the internet, I found this article: http://www.aivanoff.net/Blogs/Details/VSTOwithHSA256fail. 
For short, changing the RSAKeyValue from the "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTO\Security\Inclusion" in the registry with the RSAKeyValue of the new certificate will fix the problem. I have tried this solution and it worked but this is not the kind of solution that we want to give to our users.

I have also tried solution from the URL below, but it did not work:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1289353-91ab-4f3f-be20-6d65615441bd/security-trust-issue-only-on-some-client-machines-outlook-addin?forum=vsto

Could someone please let me know an explanation about why this error occur? And is there any other way to fix it?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157863%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and/or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6exya3kf(v=vs.80).aspx